# Learning Rust, having trouble with async_traits and borrowing. `xxxxx` dropped here while still borrowed

Tags: mongodb, rust

I've viewed so many stack overflows, but can't get my head around how to fix this.

Here are my deps:

```
[dependencies]
mongodb = { version = "2.3.1"}
tokio = "1.22.0"
twilio-openapi = "1.0.0"
async-trait = "0.1.58"
futures = "0.3.25"
```

I've created this `async_trait` repository trait for implementing various data access repositories:

```
use std::pin::Pin;

use async_trait::async_trait;
use futures::Future;
use mongodb::{bson::Document, error::Error, options::FindOneOptions, Client};

pub mod notification_settings;

#[async_trait]
pub trait Repository<'a> {
    fn with_client(client: &'a mut &Client) -> Self;
    async fn find_one<'b>(
        self,
        filter: Document,
        find_one_options: FindOneOptions,
    ) -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = Result<Option<Document>, Error>> + Send + 'b)>>;
}
```

It seems like `async_trait` sort of requires returning a `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = X> + Send + 'b)>>` Where you can specify a certain lifetime on the borrow. I'm not sure exactly why or if there are ways around this, but again still learning this.

And then here is my struct implementing the trait:

```
use std::{marker::Send, pin::Pin};

use async_trait::async_trait;
use futures::Future;
use mongodb::{bson::Document, error::Error, options::FindOneOptions, Client};

pub struct NotificationSettingsRepository<'a> {
    pub(crate) client: &'a Client,
}

#[async_trait]
impl<'a> super::Repository<'a> for NotificationSettingsRepository<'a> {
    fn with_client(client: &'a mut &Client) -> Self {
        NotificationSettingsRepository { client: client }
    }

    async fn find_one<'b>(
        self,
        filter: Document,
        find_one_options: FindOneOptions,
    ) -> Pin<Box<(dyn Future<Output = Result<Option<Document>, Error>> + Send + 'b)>> {
        let collection = self
            .client
            .database("Occasionally")
            .collection::<Document>("NotificationSettings");

        let document = collection.find_one(filter, find_one_options);

        Box::pin(async { document.await })
    }
}
```

Problem is on `collection.find_one(filter, find_one_options);` I get an error about:

```
`collection` does not live long enough
borrowed value does not live long enoughrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
notification_settings.rs(30, 5): `collection` dropped here while still borrowed
notification_settings.rs(17, 23): lifetime `'b` defined here
notification_settings.rs(21, 10): type annotation requires that `collection` is borrowed for `'b`
```

This makes some sense because the definition of find_one looks like this:

```
find_one(&self, filter: impl Into<Option<Document>>, options: impl Into<Option<FindOneOptions>>) -> Result<Option<T>>
```

So it is borrowing the collection via `&self`

I've tried a few things like adding an `async { }` wrapper on the Future of find_one. But I'm not sure what I'm doing there. Please help and thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the missing types / `use` statements (`NotificationSettingRepository`, `Document`, `FindOneOptions`, `Error`, `Client`, …) and thus provide a [mre]

Comment: An async function that returns a `Future` is a bit weird, not unheard of but not so usual. Try removing the `impl Future` trait from the return type, that is implicit because of the async machinery. That will also avoid the box and the pin and the async block.

Comment: @cafce25 thanks! I added the missing use statements and struct.

Comment: @rodrigo wow! I'm not sure how I got myself into such a strange setup before, but I just removed what you said and of course it works  too simple